# How can i inherit only few of the properties of a bootstrap pre-defined class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have added a bootstrap class and i want to remove background color and add opacity to Predefined class.
Is there a function through which this can be done easily ?

```
<div class="btn-group ">
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
<ul>
<li class="dropdown-item"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" title="Update patient info">Phone-Number</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-item"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"title="Update patient info">Patients Details</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>



Note:
when i inspect phone number it gives me background white color and on disabling it gives the desired result.
now, how can i add that to my internal css so that its remains like that
```

Comment: Do inline CSS by using style attribute. Hope this will help

Comment: you can use sass function for that and extend it

Answer (score 0):

Styles applied to a tag's ID will take precedence over styles applied to a class.

Add an id to the tag you want to style, and add css to the id. If you already have the styles written for a class, add the ID selector to them.

Inline css would also do the job, but it's not recommended.

Comment: and how can i remove the properties that a bootstrap class gives

Comment: You cannot remove a property from bootstrap, you can only overwrite it.